# Validación de campos Cliente/Empresa

Tags: php, html

quisiera saber por que mi codigo no me deja ingresar datos vacios, me explico, al hacer insert me lanza el alert como si los hubiera llenado mal, espero me explico bien. Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

// Datos de la empresa

```
            if ((!preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ, ]*$/',$empresa))) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Empresa no puede tener caracteres especiales ni numeros.");</script>';
            }
            if (strlen($empresa)>50) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Empresa es muy largo.");</script>';
            }

            if (strlen($empresa)<20) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Empresa es muy corto.");</script>';
            }

            if (strlen($fdireccion)<20) 
            {
            $errores[] = true;
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Dirección es muy corto.");</script>';
            }   
            if (strlen($fdireccion)>250) 
            {
            $errores[] = true;
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Dirección es muy largo.");</script>';
            }   

            if ((!preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ, ]*$/',$fciudad))) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Empresa no puede tener caracteres especiales ni numeros.");</script>';
            }
            if (strlen($fciudad)>15) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Ciudad es muy largo.");</script>';
            }

            if (strlen($fciudad)<4) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Ciudad es muy corto.");</script>';
            }

            if ((!preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ, ]*$/',$festado))) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Estado no puede tener caracteres especiales ni numeros.");</script>';
            }
            if (strlen($festado)>25) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Estado(Empresa)  es muy largo.");</script>';
            }

            if (strlen($festado)<5) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo Estado(Empresa)  es muy corto.");</script>';
            }

            if (!filter_var($femail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
            {
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Por favor ingrese correctamente un correo electrónico.");</script>';
            }

            if ((!preg_match('/^[A-ZÑ-&]{3,4}\d{6}(?:[A-Z\d]{3})?$/',$rfc))) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Por favor ingrese correctamente el campo RFC.");</script>';
            }

            if (strlen($fcolonia)<10) 
            {
            $errores[] = true;
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Colonia es muy corto.");</script>';
            }   

            if (strlen($fcolonia)>25) 
            {
            $errores[] = true;
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Colonia es muy largo.");</script>';
            }   

            if (!is_numeric($cp)) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Codigo Postal debe de ser númerico.");</script>';
            }
            if (strlen($cp)>5 or strlen($cp)<5) 
            {
                $errores[] = true;
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("El campo de Codigo Postal debe de tener cinco dígitos.");</script>';
            }
```

[image: imagen1]

[image: imagen2]

[image: imagen3]

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo html ?

Comment: Según este insert (if (strlen($empresa)<20) ) vacío es menor que 20 así que es normal que devuelva error. Si pusieras el HTML ayudaría.

Comment: mm, puse unas imagenes del codigo, aun no estoy en mi casa, espero sea de ayuda